# Configurable product creating programatically not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I create a configurable product programmatically and after creating it shows enable field of price and stock.But when i hit save button in admin, the price and quantity become non editable.Which table its saving this change.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
        $product_configurable = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product_configurable->setData('name', rand(30, 230));
        $product_configurable->setData('sku', rand(5, 340));
        $product_configurable->setAttributeSetId($set);
        $product_configurable->setTypeId('configurable');
        $product_configurable->setStatus(1);
        $product_configurable->setVisibility(4);
        $product_configurable->setPrice($wholedata['product']['price']);
        $product_configurable->setWeight($wholedata['product']['weight']);
        $product_configurable->setShortDescription($wholedata['product']['shortdes']);
        $product_configurable->setDescription($wholedata['product']['descrip']);
        $product_configurable->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $product_configurable->setCategoryIds(array($cat_id));
        $qty = $wholedata['product']['stock'];
        $product_configurable->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                'manage_stock' => 1,
                'min_sale_qty' => 1,
                'max_sale_qty' => 1002,
                'is_in_stock' => 0,
                'qty' => 0
            )
        );
        $product_configurable->save();
$productId = 501; // Configurable Product Id
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
            $attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
            $position = 0;
            $attributes = array(90); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
            $associatedProductIds = array(456); //Product Ids Of Associated Products


            foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
                $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $position);
                $position++;
                $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
            }
            $product->setTypeId("configurable"); // Setting Product Type As Configurable
            $product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
            $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
            $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(4); // Setting Attribute Set Id
            $product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
            $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
            $product->save();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: share your code in question

Comment: add code..........

Comment: Rakesh, Ronak I had share code.

Comment: Please follow this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html